# How to backward and step multiple times without inplace error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

I have a block of code like this:

```python
import torch
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.autograd import Variable
import torch.nn as nn


torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True)


class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_dim, out_dim):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.net = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(in_dim, 128),
            nn.Linear(128, out_dim),
            nn.Threshold(.1, .1),
        )

    def forward(self, state):
        state = Variable(state.float())
        y = self.net(state)
        return y


net = Net(21, 1)
op = optim.Adam(net.parameters())
x = []
for _ in range(300):
    x.append(torch.rand(21))
outputs = []
for i in range(len(x)):
    y = net.forward(x[i])
    outputs.append(y)
for i in range(len(x)):
    loss = torch.tensor(outputs).mean() * outputs[i]
    op.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    op.step()
```

but when I run the code I get the following error:

```
/home/yuanhao/PycharmProjects/rl/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py:173: UserWarning: Error detected in MvBackward0. Traceback of forward call that caused the error:
  File "/home/yuanhao/PycharmProjects/rl/main.py", line 94, in <module>
    y = net.forward(x[i])
  File "/home/yuanhao/PycharmProjects/rl/main.py", line 83, in forward
    y = self.net(state)
  File "/home/yuanhao/PycharmProjects/rl/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1130, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/yuanhao/PycharmProjects/rl/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/container.py", line 139, in forward
    input = module(input)
  File "/home/yuanhao/PycharmProjects/rl/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1130, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/yuanhao/PycharmProjects/rl/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/linear.py", line 114, in forward
    return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)
 (Triggered internally at  ../torch/csrc/autograd/python_anomaly_mode.cpp:102.)
  Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(  # Calls into the C++ engine to run the backward pass
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/yuanhao/PycharmProjects/rl/main.py", line 99, in <module>
    outputs[i].backward()
  File "/home/yuanhao/PycharmProjects/rl/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/_tensor.py", line 396, in backward
    torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs=inputs)
  File "/home/yuanhao/PycharmProjects/rl/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py", line 173, in backward
    Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(  # Calls into the C++ engine to run the backward pass
RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation: [torch.FloatTensor [1, 128]], which is output 0 of AsStridedBackward0, is at version 2; expected version 1 instead. Hint: the backtrace further above shows the operation that failed to compute its gradient. The variable in question was changed in there or anywhere later. Good luck!
```

It sames that the in-place operation happens in the network, caused by the `op.step()`, how can I fix this? I want to update the model parameter step by step in a batch (300 in this case), BUT only after I have all the model outputs of that batch, since I need those outputs to compute the loss.

Comment: What is nn. ?  Can't test your code out to troubleshoot without it.

Comment: @Matt, Sorry about that, I forget to paste the imported packages. I have now edited it.

Comment: Your error is coming from the line: op.step() line.... if I change it to op.step instead everything executes fine without any errors.  Although I have no idea what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: I just want to update the model multiple times using the loss that is calculated by all outputs of the model. (I have tried just update one time instead of multiple times in the last for loop, and it runs fine). My guess is that the calculate the gradient of the loss need the model parameter when the loss is calculated, but op.step() will update that parameter in place so that the origin parameters are no longer available?